# Create tag from using ASP Tokken Input

Tags: c#, asp.net, tags, jquery-tokeninput

I can easily create tags using ASPTokkenInput and saved in database in the form of string.

For example : I created 3 tags like `JAVA  C#  Entity`

and saved these tags in database like `java,c#,entity`

But after fetching using sql query from database, I need to create this string back in the form of TAGS in ASPTokenInput. 
How can I create tags from .cs page in C#?

Here is the code for creating tags
**ASPX Page**

```
<ati:ASPTokenInput ID="StateNameBox" runat="server" 
 RequestHandlerPath="SearchItemList.aspx?type=StateName"
 OnListChanged="StateName_ListChanged" Theme="facebook" 
 PostbackOnItemAdded="True" PostbackOnItemRemoved="True"
 HintText="Start Typing StateName..." PreventDuplicates="True"/>

 <asp:ListBox ID="StateNameList" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="150px" 
 style="display:none;" />
```

**.csPage**

```
  protected void StateName_ListChanged(object sender, ASPTokenInput.ListChangedEventArgs e)
 {
        if (e.Action == ASPTokenInput.ListChangeActions.Add)
            StateNameList.Items.Add(e.Item.name);
        else
        {
            for (int n = StateNameList.Items.Count - 1; n >= 0; --n)
            {
                string removelistitem = e.Item.name;
                if (StateNameList.Items[n].ToString().Contains(removelistitem))
                {
                    StateNameList.Items.RemoveAt(n);
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

Buttonclick to save in database

```
String state = "";
for (int j = 0; j < StateNameList.Items.Count; j++)
{
   state = (StateNameList.Items[j].Text)+","+state;
}
```

Save **state string** in to the database

Now, i am fetch this string from database and need to create tags in ASPTokenInput

```
 conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
 objsqlconn = new SqlConnection(conn);

 objsqlconn.Open();
 objcmd = new SqlCommand("Select state from StateName where stateId='1'");
 sqlread = objcmd.ExecuteReader();

 String statename = "";
  if (sqlread.Read())
  {
    statename = sqlread.GetString(0);
  }

 String[] statelist = statename.Split(',');
 for(int i=0;i<statelist.Length;i++){

    //now here what i want to do for createing tags again in ASPTokenInput

 }
```

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: post the code you tried..also explain with example whats the output you are looking for